# Amazon Linux - Running Composer as Apache User?

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, amazon-linux

I have a webhook for my application that currently does this:

```
cd /var/www/html; git pull origin master; /usr/local/bin/composer dump-autoload; php artisan migrate
```

I've been able to get all the commands above to work except the `composer dump-autoload` command.

When I log into the server as `ec2-user` and run `sudo -u apache /usr/local/bin/composer dump-autoload`, the command runs.  But if I hit the endpoint that runs this command through a PHP script using `shell_exec`, this does not work.

Is there a way for me to get `apache` user to run this command on its own?

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable by modifying your sudoers file.

`visudo`

Add the line:

`ec2-user ALL=(apache) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check if the apache user does have writing privileges under Laravel directory. composer will try to write in 'vendors' directory.

Regards.